# How to make a table less cramped

Tags: tables, math-mode, arrays

I used [MathPix](https://mathpix.com/) OCR program to get the Latex code of this table.

[image]

When I tried to use the tabular mode, all the "a" and "g" lost the math font. So I had to put $$ between each varible.

```
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline {\text { I }} & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1 & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77 & 9,2 \\
\cline { 2 - 11 } & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2 & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88 & 10,2 \\
\cline { 2 - 11 } & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3 & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99 & 10,2 \\
\hline{\text { II }} & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1^{\prime} & 1,789 & 0,559 & 0,559 & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
\cline { 2 - 11 } & & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2^{\prime} & & 1,841 & 0,374 & 1,766 & 3,98 \\
\cline { 2 - 11 } & & & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3^{\prime} & & & 1,936 & 1,08 & 3,016 \\
\hline \text { III } & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & & & 0,811 & 0,846 & 0,558 & & \\
\hline
\end{array}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My main advice for giving your table a less-cramped look is to get rid of all vertical rules and employ fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

And, in order to make the table more *readable*, I'd also align the numbers in the final five columns on their respective decimal markers. Finally, there's no need to write `^{\prime}` unless you possess a moderate to severe self-loathing streak. Just write `'` instead and instantaneously make the *input* more readable. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
       
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} % use "," as decimal marker

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} % suppress left-hand side whitespace padding
              l 
              *{5}{c}
              *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
              *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}
              @{} } % % suppress right-hand side whitespace padding
\toprule 
\mathrm{I}   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1 & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77 & 9,2  \\
             & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2 & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88 & 10,2 \\
             & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3 & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99 & 10,2 \\
\addlinespace
\mathrm{II}  & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1' & 1,789 & 0,559 & 0,559 & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
             & & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2' & & 1,841 & 0,374 & 1,766 & 3,98 \\
             & & & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3' & & & 1,936 & 1,08 & 3,016 \\
\addlinespace
\mathrm{III} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & & & 0,811 & 0,846 & 0,558 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I love that the two answers currently provided both do a good job of solving the problem while having slightly different styles. I personally have a mild preference for what @CarLaTeX did, but (a) that preference could easily change based on the context of the table relative to other objects in the document, and (b) is 100% subjective, as opposed to the only slightly subjective notion that decimal markers (i.e., commas here) should be aligned. (Technically subjective, I suppose, but I believe universally agreed on.)

Answer (score 9):

I would do something like this, with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\NewColumnType{A}[1][1.4]{Q[
    si={
    group-digits  = false,
    table-format=#1,
    table-number-alignment=center,
    output-decimal-marker={,}
    },
    c]}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={l*{5}{c}*{3}{A}A[1.3]A[2.3]},
 %   row{1}={guard}, <--- in case you would add a header row  
    column{1}={mode=text},
    column{2-Z}={mode=math},
    hline{1,4,7,Z}={}
    }
 I & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1 & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77 & 9,2 \\
& a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2 & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88 & 10,2 \\
 & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3 & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99 & 10,2 \\
 II  & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1' & 1,789 & 0,559 & 0,559 & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
& & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2' & & 1,841 & 0,374 & 1,766 & 3,98 \\
 & & & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3' & & & 1,936 & 1,08 & 3,016 \\
 III  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & & & 0,811 & 0,846 & 0,558 & & \\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Since the OP would appear to want to use the `,` (comma) symbol as the decimal marker, you may want to add the option `output-decimal-marker={,}` to the list of arguments of `si{...}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, corrected!

Answer (score 7):

You don't give much context about what the table is supposed to show.

I'd definitely use a `table` environment with its caption, so you have a place where to explain the data.

Since the table is quite wide, it may make sense to make it as wide as the text width, see the second realization with `tabular*`. This however depends on your page setup: don't widen the table if it's not above, say, 80% of the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}% no left padding
  c % centered column
  *{5}{>{$}c<{$}}% five math columns
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}% three numeric columns
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  @{}% no right padding
}
\toprule
I   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1  & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77  &  9,2  \\
    & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2  & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88  & 10,2  \\
    & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3  & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99  & 10,2  \\
\midrule
II  & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1' & 1,789  & 0,559  & 0,559  & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
    &        & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2' &        & 1,841  & 0,374  & 1,766 & 3,98  \\
    &        &        & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3' &        &        & 1,936  & 1,08  & 3,016 \\
\midrule
III & x_1    & x_2    & x_3    &     &      &        & 0,811  & 0,846  & 0,558 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{A table with values, where you should also specify the meaning of the rows and columns}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% no left padding
  l % left-aligned column
  *{5}{>{$}c<{$}}% five math columns
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}% three numeric columns
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  @{}% no right padding
}
\toprule
I   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1  & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77  &  9,2  \\
    & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2  & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88  & 10,2  \\
    & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3  & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99  & 10,2  \\
\midrule
II  & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1' & 1,789  & 0,559  & 0,559  & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
    &        & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2' &        & 1,841  & 0,374  & 1,766 & 3,98  \\
    &        &        & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3' &        &        & 1,936  & 1,08  & 3,016 \\
\midrule
III & x_1    & x_2    & x_3    &     &      &        & 0,811  & 0,846  & 0,558 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{A table with values, where you should also specify the meaning of the rows and columns}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try using the array package and defining a new column type:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}c<{$}}
```

and replace in the **tabular environment** with `\usepackage{tabularx}`. The pointer `>` will add the `{$}` on the left side and `<` add a `{$}` on the right side. In addition, put these two commands in your preamble to manipulate the line and column spacing:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % The default is 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 1.0 = 100%, 1.5 = 150%, ...
```

The smaller the value inside the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{}` command, the smaller the whitespace inside the cell, however this does not interfere with line spacing, so adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{}` is essential to compensate for the other command.

Putting it all together:

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}c<{$}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tabular}{|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|}
        \hline 
        {\text { I }} & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 & S_1 & 2,1161 & 0,1254 & 0,1397 & 0,77 & 9,2 \\
        \cline 
        { 2 - 11 } & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 & S_2 & 0,1254 & 1,1675 & 0,1768 & 0,88 & 10,2 \\
        \cline 
        { 2 - 11 } & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & b_3 & S_3 & 0,1397 & 0,1768 & 1,2168 & 0,99 & 10,2 \\
        \hline
        {\text { II }} & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} & y_1 & S_1^{\prime} & 1,789 & 0,559 & 0,559 & 2,236 & 5,143 \\
        \cline 
        { 2 - 11 } & & g_{22} & g_{23} & y_2 & S_2^{\prime} & & 1,841 & 0,374 & 1,766 & 3,98 \\
        \cline 
        { 2 - 11 } & & & g_{33} & y_3 & S_3^{\prime} & & & 1,936 & 1,08 & 3,016 \\
        \hline 
        \text { III } & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & & & 0,811 & 0,846 & 0,558 & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In what sense does replacing the `array` environment with a `tabular ` environment create output that looks less cramped?

Comment: @Mico In no sense ('-'), I forgot to put the part to make it less tight. I already edited my post. I just used the tabular environment because that is what I am most used to using.

Comment: The claim that "The smaller the value inside the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{}` command, the smaller the letter compression inside the table" is puzzling. For sure, the parameter `\tabcolsep` is not related to "cell compression"; instead, it governs the amount of whitespace padding that's inserted on both sides of a cell in a `tabular`-like environment.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll edit the post